# Laravel: How do I get data from this pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pivot-table, laravel-5.3

**SOLVED**: answer posted below

How can I get values from this pivot and specifications table?

I want to display this in a template like:

-Model (name from specifications table)

--Brand (attribute form pivot table): example1 (value from pivot table)

--Model (attribute form pivot table): example123 (value from pivot table)
...

---

In ProductController I tried returning something like this `$product = Product::with('specifications')->first();`, but then I can get only data from specifications table and if I try `$product = Product::with('product_specification')->first();` I get error `Call to undefined relationship [product_specification] on model [App\Product].`

---

Pivot table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('product_specification', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('specification_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('specification_id')->references('id')->on('specifications')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('attribute');
        $table->string('value');
    });
}
```

Specifications table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('specifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Product model:

```
public function specifications() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Specification::class, 'product_specification');
}
```

Comment: What have you done to `How can I get values from this pivot and specifications table?` @rudolph

Comment: @AndyK In ProductController I tried returning something like this `$product = Product::with('specifications')->first();`, but then I can get only data from specifications table and if I try `$product = Product::with('product_specification')->first();` I get error `Call to undefined relationship [product_specification] on model [App\Product].`

Comment: put it in the question mate. We have to know that! @rudolph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add withPivot() to my Product model

```
public function specifications() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Specification::class, 'product_specification')->withPivot('attribute', 'value');
}
```

And then in template:

```
foreach($product->specifications as $specification) {
    echo 'name: ' . $specification->name . ' attribute: ' . $specification->pivot->attribute . ' value ' . $specification->pivot->value . '</br>';
}
```